Where are the user account details, such as, user id, password, group, etc. stored in an OpenID Connect deployment?
In comparison to LDAP servers, where are user the account details, such as, user id, password, group, etc. stored in an OpenID Connect deployment?  I understand that the user gets redirected by the application (RP-Relying Party) to the Authorization server (OP-OpenID Provider) and it prompts the user to provide the credentials.  But, how does the OP authneticate the user?  Does it contain the user account details within itself or does it refer to a Resource Server?  Also, is there a way to include groups as a claim to be included in the scope of the JWT, if it isn't already a part of it?
Thanks!

It depends on a configuration on identity provider. In Okta you can have users which are in AD/LDAP, as well as users who are created directly in Okta. So authentication can happen against Okta's own database or external provider (LDAP, SAML, OIDC based).
Resource Server is never considered a user store, as its only role in OIDC flow is to provide a specific resource/service to a client.
In Okta you can have groups to be configured as claims. You can look at this article to get an idea on how it can be achieved.
